Pandas df to Apache iceberg table
I'm trying to insert into a Iceberg table, but I'm getting issues due to the data types mismatching. I've pasted a part of my code. The error message I'm getting is :
"errorMessage": "Schema change detected: {'new_columns': {}, 'modified_columns': {'low': 'decimal(13,10)', 'close': 'decimal(13,10)', 'open': 'decimal(13,10).'.....
import json
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 30
    df['open'] = df['open'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x).quantize(Decimal('0.0000000000')))
    df['high'] = df['high'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x).quantize(Decimal('0.0000000000')))
    df['low'] = df['low'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x).quantize(Decimal('0.0000000000')))
    df['close'] = df['close'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x).quantize(Decimal('0.0000000000')))
    df['adjustedclose'] = df['adjustedclose'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(x).quantize(Decimal('0.0000000000')))

    #print(df.columns)
    print(df.dtypes)
    
    #print(df.head(10))
    
    wr.athena.to_iceberg(
        df=df,
        database='market_test',
        table='price',
        table_location='s3://blah',
       temp_path='s3://blah-temp',
        data_source = 'AwsDataCatalog'
    )

Error message
{
  "errorMessage": "Schema change detected: {'new_columns': {}, 'modified_columns': {'open': 'decimal(13,10)', 'high': 'decimal(13,10)', 'adjustedclose': 'decimal(13,10)', 'close': 'decimal(13,10)', 'low': 'decimal(13,10)', 'volume': 'bigint'}, 'missing_columns': {}}",
  "errorType": "InvalidArgumentValue",
  "requestId": "[]",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 40, in lambda_handler\n    wr.athena.to_iceberg(\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/_config.py\", line 715, in wrapper\n    return function(**args)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/_utils.py\", line 178, in inner\n    return func(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/awswrangler/athena/_write_iceberg.py\", line 434, in to_iceberg\n    raise exceptions.InvalidArgumentValue(f\"Schema change detected: {schema_differences}\")\n"
  ]
}```


Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word traceback. You can surround the report with 3 before and 3 after to properly format the output.
